# Rules help to get contact_id from crm-core

Tags: rules

Having a hard time trying to create a rule to 'Clear URL(s) from the page cache.'

Specifically I want to clear the path - `crm-core/contact/[contact_id]/activity/[activity_id]`
**example: crm-core/contact/17/activity/39**

My rule is like this.

Event: After updating an existing field collection item (which is attached to crm-activity)

Conditions - Entity has field

Parameter: `Entity: [crm-core-activity], Field: field_activity_participants`

here is what my url path looks like

> crm-core/contact/[field-collection-item:host-entity:field-activity-participants:0:uid]/activity/[field-collection-item:host-entity:activity-id]

I am thinking the '`participants:0:uid` is NOT the same as crm-core's `[contact_id]`..also not sure How I can expose it - have tried many variation of 'entity has field' to see if contact_id is displayed somewhere with no luck.